# Sparql query times out with a transitive temp memory error message

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am running the following query to get visitor attraction in Italy

```
select distinct ?poi where {?company a dbpedia-owl:Place ; rdfs:label ?poiName; dcterms:subject/skos:broader* category:Visitor_attractions_in_Italy }
```

But I get the following error.

```
Virtuoso 42000 Error TN...: Exceeded 1000000000 bytes in transitive temp memory. use t_distinct, t_max or more T_MAX_memory options to limit the search or increase the pool SPARQL query: define sql:big-data-const 0 #output-format:application/sparql-results+json define input:default-graph-uri PREFIX owl: PREFIX xsd: PREFIX rdfs: PREFIX rdf: PREFIX foaf: PREFIX dc: PREFIX : PREFIX dbpedia2: PREFIX dbpedia: PREFIX skos: select distinct ?poi where {?company a dbpedia-owl:Place ; rdfs:label ?poiName; dcterms:subject/skos:broader* category:Visitor_attractions_in_Italy }
```

I get this Error even If i use limit 10 at the end of the query. I know this may be a time consuming query but not sure how to break this query down such that at the end I get all the visitor attractions.

Comment: answers.semanticweb.com has an answer to this problem: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/26389/finding-all-possible-categories-between-one-given-and-main-classification-with-dbpedia-and-sparql .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone ran into this same type of problem and asked about it on answers.semanticweb.com: [Finding all possible categories between one given and Main classification with DBpedia and SPARQL](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/26389/finding-all-possible-categories-between-one-given-and-main-classification-with-dbpedia-and-sparql).  The somewhat unsatisfying answer provided there is the answer here, too:  make a decision about how deep you actually need to go, and rather than using *, use the {} notation to indicate a maximum number of repetitions of skos:broader.  E.g.,

```
select distinct ?poi where {
  ?poi a dbpedia-owl:Place ;
       dcterms:subject/skos:broader{,10} category:Visitor_attractions_in_Italy
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=%20%20%20%20select%20distinct%20%3Fpoi%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fpoi%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3APlace%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dcterms%3Asubject%2Fskos%3Abroader%7B%2C10%7D%20category%3AVisitor_attractions_in_Italy%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The {} notation to indicate number of repetitions is actually not a part of the standard, though it was in earlier drafts of it.  The DBpedia endpoint, which is based on Virtuoso, still supports it, though.

Comment: So overall , it is a trial and error process to see how deep we can go?

Comment: Also, I am not sure if this is caused by transitive cycles or just too many sub categories to traverse for the server.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem of transitive cycles, because the SPARQL semantics should handle that.  Otherwise, data like `x p y . y p x.` should cause problems with a query like `?a p* ?b`. There are *lots* of categories on Wikipedia, though, so traversing the graph probably requires a fair amount of memory.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It's not just the number of categories, it's also their structure. Would you have guessed that Category:United States is (indirectly) under Category:Theocracies?

Comment: @svick 0) skos:broader isn't a type hierarchy; it's for arranging topics.  1) [skos:broader isn't transitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-skos-reference-20090818/#L2413), so just because `Cat:US skos:broader* Cat:Theocracies` doesn't mean that `Cat:US skos:broader Cat:Theocracies`.  It's not *all* that surprising that there might be some distant link, then.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I get that. What I meant is that if the category structure was reasonable, doing `?x skos:broader* Cat:Theocracies` might have worked reasonably well, even if the total number of categories was as huge as it is. But with the current structure, you're likely to get huge number of indirect subcategories that you're not interested in.

Comment: Also, try a search like this to see *what* the intermediate categories are: `select distinct * where { category:United_States skos:broader{,9} ?mid . ?mid skos:broader{,9} category:Theocracies .}`.  When you see some of the results, e.g., Cold War, Aftermath of World War II,  Wars involving Iran, Military History of British India, it's not too hard to see how you could get to Theocracies.

Comment: The category structure is a bit messy, but it's not all that unreasonable.  It's just that skos:broader might be capturing something different than what you expect it to.  E.g., rather than looking for things related to some category, why not look to see if there are any DBpedia ontology classes that match better?